# Max of moving average in Matlab struct

Tags: matlab

I've got a dataset in a struct with eight 12x4 cell and I want to compute the moving average of each cell and find the maximum of that.
I saw that I can compute the maximum of a struct with this example:

```
M = randn(3, 20, 2);
C = squeeze(mat2cell(M,3,ones(20,1),[1 1]))
Cmax = cellfun(@max, C)
```

and it works perfectly for me, but I'd need first to compute the moving average, without the conversion cell2mat. Is it possible?

Comment: Why without the conversion cell2mat? Use a for loop...

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you want the moving average to do? What dimension are you traversing? Given some known values, what do you want the result to be?

Comment: “Moving average” is typically computed using `conv`. Do you want to compute that along the vectors in each cell? Or do you want to compute that across cells? Or do you by chance mean something else than the convolution?